# Using AJAX on a file from your own library in code igniter 4

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am creating a simple API to call methods from my php classes using JQuery and AJAX. I have a question how to enter the path in AJAX to refer to a given file from the Libraries directory (photo 2)?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmm4D.png)
photo 2:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdCLR.png)

Comment: What exactly have you tried. Please provide the actual code and not the image of the code. Plus "enter image description here" gives the impression that you could not even be bothered to do... exactly what it says. Please conside that people volunteer to help you... and what kind of impression you give.

Answer (score 0):

as you mentioned this is a custom library so if u want to user your library classes first `make a controller` (or use one you have) to call it from there .
and if u have file for that library you **Must** put it on public folder otherwise make separate library in whole **new different project** and add it in https://packagist.org/ then add it to your project with composer .